# ADMOB ad on device Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

First - I TRIED the answers here, THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!!!!!!!!

Ok, then hello :)

I have a problem with my ad, it is showing "Required xml attribute "adSize" was missing" on my device,

here is the xml code I am using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"       
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYYY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/coins2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:src="@drawable/lifelifelife" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Buy extra life for one turn! cost 200 coins :)" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="Get 2 coins for every click! cost 1000 coins :)" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:text="Go back to game" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any problem here? or the problem is in my shop.java class?

Comment: If you've already tried some solutions that should work but don't then it's worth mentioning them and how they didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try adding the adview from the code. For example:

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.popup1);
layout.addView(adView);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely a duplicate.

In your XML you have defined your AdView using a class from the Play Services library, but you are using the XML namespace from the old AdMob-6.4.1 library. You *should* be using the Play Services namespace ie

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

As always see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals for details